# Socket.io - io.sockets.clients().length how to get unique list of connected clients

Tags: socket.io

I use socket.io to open a socket from my client to my node.js server. I also push the number of connected users to all clients every 10 seconds using `io.sockets.clients().length`, the problem with this value is, that it doesn't check if the same user has opened multiple tabs with the same page.

Is there a way to get a list of unique clients that are connected in socket.io?

Comment: What do you mean "does not check" -- it reports more open connections than you expect or less than you expect?

Comment: the value is correct, it gives me all open sockets, though I need a different value, instead of all open sockets I need "all unique clients that are connected".

Comment: do you mean that two open tabs share the same socket in your case? (chrome?)

Comment: Two open tabs by the same user are two sockets, which is fine. But I need to figure out how many clients are uniquely connected to my server. I'm not sure how to do this with socket.io, do I just generate a value on the client side which I send to the server on the connection? (the value would be a combination of the "user IP"+"browser"+"browser version"+etc.)

Comment: what is your definition of a client? a person? a computer? a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a browser cookies.

Here is the example:

[How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are locking unique ID for each person.

Client code.

//When user connect to socket server to emit some info event like this
`socket.emit('userInfo','clintUniqueID');//like mailid ID,username,anything but its unique`

//When user open other tabs

```
socket.on('multipleTabs',function(data){
    //Your operation for client side    
     //example 
      alert('you are open multiple tabs');});
```

Server code:

```
var connection={}; //socket.io connection each user 
var usersList=[];//This list only contain unique ID for each connection
socket.on('userInfo',function(data){//emit by client (user)
 connection[socket.id]=socket; // just for connection
 var(var i=0;i<usersList.length;i++)
     {
           if(usersList[i]==data)//Here you store user unique ID like mailID,Username etc
             {
                  //user open multiple tabs  
                  //Any operation server site
                  //if you want to do any operation in  client site
                    socket.emit('multipleTabs','userAlreadyExit');



       }else
           {
                        if(i==usersList.length-1)
                           {
                               usersList.push(data);//store socket.id 
                                  }

                     }
 });
```

Now it will work check it

Comment: That doesn't work, socket.id doesn't give me a unique ID for each client, opening multiple tabs gives me different socket.id's. Also the "userInfo" function is not being handled on the server.

Comment: change socket.on('info',function(data){}); to socket.on('userInfo',function(data){});

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that "socket.id" is not uniquely identifying a client

Comment: but you must specify uniqueID in socket.emit('userInfo','UNIQUEID');

Comment: may be its mailid,username any thing